# Adding one hash table to another based on a common value

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Windows has two PowerShell commands for getting information about Disks `Get-PhysicalDisk` and `Get-Disk`.

I running the command `Get-PhysicalDisk` and then trying to append the output of the command with the result from `Get-Disk` using a common value that exists in the output of both commands, this value is `SerialNumber`.

I'm convinced this is a simple hash table requirement I can't wrap my head around it.

```
$PhysicalDisks = Get-PhysicalDisk |
                 Select OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, BusType, FriendlyName,
                     Manufacturer, SerialNumber
foreach ($Disk in $PhysicalDisks) {
    $AdditionalDiskInfo = Get-Disk |
                          Where SerialNumber -eq $_.SerialNumber |
                          select PartitionStyle, ProvisioningType,
                              NumberOfPartitions, Signature

    # I know this isn't anywhere near correct, I'm just trying to explain my
    # end goal :)
    #$PhysicalDisks + $AdditionalDiskInfo |
    #    Where $PhysicalDisks.SerialNumber -eq $AdditionalDiskInfo.SerialNumber
}
```

My expected result would be the combining of this:

```
PS> Get-PhysicalDisk | Select OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, BusType,                     
FriendlyName, Manufacturer, SerialNumber
OperationalStatus : OK
HealthStatus      : Healthy
BusType           : SATA
FriendlyName      : KINGSTON SV310S37A960G
Manufacturer      : 
SerialNumber      : 50026B724800A34E
```

and this:

```
PS> Get-Disk | Where SerialNumber -eq "50026B724800A34E" | select PartitionStyle, ProvisioningType, NumberOfPartitions, Signature | Format-list
PartitionStyle     : MBR
ProvisioningType   : Fixed
NumberOfPartitions : 2
Signature          : 1364200743
```

to give me this:

```
OperationalStatus : OK
HealthStatus      : Healthy
BusType           : SATA
FriendlyName      : KINGSTON SV310S37A960G
Manufacturer      : 
SerialNumber      : 50026B724800A34E
PartitionStyle    : MBR
ProvisioningType  : Fixed
NumberOfPartitions: 2
Signature         : 1364200743
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking out `Add-Member`. You can use it to add the few properties you need to `$disk`

Comment: Your example above is objects, so I assumed the title was wrong. Please fix one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build custom objects in your loop like this:

```
foreach ($Disk in $PhysicalDisks) {
    $info = Get-Disk |
            Where-Object { $Disk.SerialNumber -eq $_.SerialNumber.Trim() }

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'OperationalStatus'  = $Disk.OperationalStatus
        'HealthStatus'       = $Disk.HealthStatus
        'BusType'            = $Disk.BusType
        'FriendlyName'       = $Disk.FriendlyName
        'Manufacturer'       = $Disk.Manufacturer
        'SerialNumber'       = $Disk.SerialNumber
        'PartitionStyle'     = $info.PartitionStyle
        'ProvisioningType'   = $info.ProvisioningType
        'NumberOfPartitions' = $info.NumberOfPartitions
        'Signature'          = $info.Signature
    }
}
```

However, it'd probably simpler to create a hashtable mapping serial numbers to `Get-Disk` data, and then add the relevant information as calculated properties where you look up the information by serial number.

```
$info = @{}
Get-Disk | ForEach-Object {
    $info[$_.SerialNumber.Trim()] = $_
}

Get-PhysicalDisk |
    Select-Object OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, BusType, FriendlyName,
        Manufacturer, SerialNumber,
        @{n='PartitionStyle';e={$info[$_.SerialNumber].PartitionStyle}},
        @{n='ProvisioningType';e={$info[$_.SerialNumber].ProvisioningType}},
        @{n='NumberOfPartitions';e={$info[$_.SerialNumber].NumberOfPartitions}},
        @{n='Signature';e={$info[$_.SerialNumber].Signature}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea it could be done this way and there's a lot of new things for me to wrap my head around here. Can you kindly explain what's happening on this line `$info[$_.SerialNumber] = $_`?

Comment: That is creating an entry in the hashtable `$info` mapping the current disk object to its serial number. Roughly the same as if you did `$info['50026B724800A34E'] = Get-Disk -SerialNumber '50026B724800A34E'`.

Comment: Ah I see, so `$_` is a reference to all output from `Get-Disk`? I've only ever seen it used in `$_.SomeKey` to get specific values - very good to know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: *so `$_` is a reference to all output from `Get-Disk`?* No. It's a reference to the current object in a pipeline.

Comment: I guess, you meant **`$Disk.`** `SerialNumber` in `Get-Disk | Where-Object { SerialNumber -eq $_.SerialNumber }`. But that is not the whole issue in this solution, it appears (at least in my case) that the `SerialNumber` from `Get-Disk` has leading spaces and the one from `Get-PhysicalDisk` not, which makes it little complexer. This probably means that you need to trim the serial number (`$_.SerialNumber.Trim()`) before comparing (and/or indexing) it.

Comment: @iRon Indeed that is what I meant. As for differences in the `SerialNumber` properties returned by `Get-Disk` and `Get-PhysicalDisk`: thanks for the heads up. I only have a Win7 test box at my disposal here and thus couldn't test the code. Updated my answer.